# IEnumerable<T> cant Enumerate or is not compatible as seq<T>

Tags: .net, f#

Im new at F# but Seq should be the same as a IEnumerable?

```
let test = makeAsyncRequestPage "some web page"
        |> Async.RunSynchronously
        |> getPageResult //Returns a Seq<HtmlNode>
        |> Seq.head<HtmlNode>
        |> fun h -> h.ChildNodes.Nodes //IEnumerable<HtmlNode>
        |> fun h -> [for row in h -> row]
```

I get error when running the code, `h` is the IEnumerable and the following error appears:

`'The type '(unit -> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<HtmlNode>)' is not a type whose values can be enumerated with this syntax, i.e. is not compatible with either seq<_>, IEnumerable<_> or IEnumerable and does not have a GetEnumerator method'`

What is wrong, this should just work as what im informed.

Comment: You are missing a `()` argument somewhere, probably after `h.ChildNodes.Nodes` so you are trying to enumerate a function `unit -> IEnumerable<HtmlNode>` instead of an `IEnumerable<HtmlNode>`.

Comment: Thanks that was the solution, been looking blind on it for a wile now.

Comment: How did you see it, cant really see it from the error message?

Comment: Usually when you have a function when you expect a value, it means you haven't supplied enough arguments somewhere. The error message suggests the argument in your for expression has the wrong type, which is the result of `h.Child.Nodes` in the previous line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`h.ChildNodes.Nodes` is a method, so you need to apply a `unit` argument:

```
let test = makeAsyncRequestPage "some web page"
        |> Async.RunSynchronously
        |> getPageResult //Returns a Seq<HtmlNode>
        |> Seq.head<HtmlNode>
        |> fun h -> h.ChildNodes.Nodes ()
        |> fun h -> [for row in h -> row]
```

Comment: Also you don't need to specify the type parameter on the `Seq.head` call. I might be inclined to merge the last two lambda expressions into one: `|> fun h -> [for row in h.ChildNodes.Nodes() -> row]`